# Emulating Linux binaries under Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, binary, emulation

How do I run Linux binaries under Mac OS X?

Googling around I found a couple of emulators but none for running Linux binaries on a Mac. There are quite a few posts about running Mac OS X on Linux and that kind of stuff - but that's the opposite of what I want to do.

Update:

Thanks for all the answers! I am fully aware of MacPorts and Fink or any of the other things; and no, I do not want any of these utilities, and I do not want any of the package managers, I prefer to compile things myself. I also have Parallels and could set up virtual machines and all that jazz...

The only thing I want to do is to find a way to run a binary that I do not have the source code for and has been compiled for Linux, but I do not want to run it under Linux but under Mac OS X. Therefore my question about emulators.

Comment: If your just looking to run software from the *nix/POSIX world it will probably compile provided it doesn't depend on OS specific libraries.  Fink or MacPorts can help with this somewhat.

Comment: I can't think of any software that's available for Linux, but not for Mac (sadly, since I'm a Linux guy). Why are you looking for such a thing?

Comment: Team Fortress 2 dedicated server is an example that is Windows and Linux only :-/

Comment: @David Cloudera Manager

Comment: Great question! I too, have a piece of enterprise software that runs in Linux, but my development machine is a Mac. Hopefully someone comes up with a solution - emulation layer for Linux binaries on Mac.

Answer (score 7):

Well there is a project introducing something like Linux's binfmt_misc to OS X so now what you need is an ELF loader, a dynamic linker that can load both Mach-O and ELF, and some mechanism to translate Linux calls to OS X ones.

Just for inspiration, you can implement the dynamic linker in the fashion that it ignores filename extension - both libfoo.so.1 (as an Linux ELF) and libfoo.1.dylib (as an Mach-O) can be loaded so that OS X versions of system libraries can be reused so that you do not need to write a "hosted on OS X" libc.so and syscalls can be handled by an kext that translates Linux calls to OS X ones in kernel.

Or, in an more elegant way, implement a stripped down Linux kernel as a kext that makes the OS X kernel a dual-purpose. However that will require you to use two sets of libraries. (Binaries do not clash so it is largely okay)

Comment: Do you have a link for this?

Answer (score 6):

Set up a virtual machine (I personally use VMWare Fusion) and then install whatever distro of Linux you desire on the virtual machine.

Or, if you have the source to the Linux program, chances are you can recompile it on a Mac and run it natively.  If you install [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), you can install a lot of open source programs without much trouble.

Comment: I added links to Fink and DarwinPorts because they're usually easier than downloading source and trying to compile it, realizing you need to install something else first, and downloading it and trying to compile it, etc etc etc.

Comment: Cool. It's actually MacPorts now, by the way. ;)

Answer (score 6):

I recently found [Noah](https://github.com/linux-noah/noah), which you can use to run Linux binaries on macOS. You can install Noah via homebrew (`brew install linux-noah/noah/noah`). Then you should be able to do this:

```
noah linux_binary
```

In my experience the behavior of the binary matches what I see on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I got the error `fatal error: runtime: cannot reserve arena virtual address space` trying to execute a Go program.

Comment: @Chang Qian, that's no good. I just tried something similar with a small Go program and saw the same error. Maybe Noah should be more specifically said to allow you to run Linux *C* binaries on macOS. C programs were all I had really tried before.

Comment: Maybe Docker for Mac is the ultimate solution.

Comment: I get an error "operation not permitted" when using Noah, Although I have given the terminal full Disk Access

Answer (score 4):

You might have some luck with running Linux executables under Mac OS X using Qemu's [User Space Emulator](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#QEMU-User-space-emulator)

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to go the virtualization route, consider also [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

Also, if you only need UNIX like command line tools, there is the [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) project. This is basically how I set up `git` on my mac: after having installed MacPorts you just have to run the `sudo port install git` command to install `git` on your system.

Answer (score 2):

`noah` does not allow the binaries to execute properly for me.  Use [Docker Desktop for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/).

Just do:
`docker pull centos:latest # 73MB CentOS docker image`

Make a folder for what is needed to run your binary, and in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos
COPY your_binary /bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["your_binary"]
```

and you can build it with

`docker build -t image_name`

then execute with

`docker run image_name` as if it were the binary itself.  Worked for me.  Hope it helps someone else.  And if you need specific outputs or to store files somewhere you can mount volumes onto the docker with `-v`, for example:

`docker run -v path_to_my_stuff:/docker_stuff image_name`,

though adding a `WORKDIR /docker_stuff` line to the `Dockerfile` before `ENTRYPOINT` is probably best.

If you change `ENTRYPOINT` to

`ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c"]` 
and add

`CMD ["your_binary"]`

underneath it, you can actually pass the command into the image like

```
docker run -v path_on_local:/in_container_path image_name "your_binary some_parameters -optionrequiringzerowhitespacebeforeinputvalue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try Actually Portable Executable in Linux-like chroot